# Warning: include(Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, error, server-setup, local.xml

I have uploaded my website from local environment to a live server.  I changed the **config.xml** file and removed the **local.xml** file but it is causing the following error:

```
    Warning: include(Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home1/belghiti/chamsse.ma/BETA/chamsse/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

#0 /home1/belghiti/chamsse.ma/BETA/chamsse/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(94): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(Mage/Co...', '/home1/belghiti...', 94, Array)
#1 /home1/belghiti/chamsse.ma/BETA/chamsse/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(94): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Mage_Core_Contr...')
#3 /home1/belghiti/chamsse.ma/BETA/chamsse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(138): spl_autoload_call('Mage_Core_Contr...')
#4 /home1/belghiti/chamsse.ma/BETA/chamsse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(764): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->init()
#5 /home1/belghiti/chamsse.ma/BETA/chamsse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1113): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initFrontController()
#6 /home1/belghiti/chamsse.ma/BETA/chamsse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Model_App->getFrontController()
#7 /home1/belghiti/chamsse.ma/BETA/chamsse/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 /home1/belghiti/chamsse.ma/BETA/chamsse/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
1. Check your PHP version. Magento 1.9 does not support PHP 7.x.
2. Check your file permissions. Run the following to check Production permissions for Magento:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && find . -type d -exec chmod 550 {} \; && find var/ -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && find media/ -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && find var/ -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find media/ -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && chmod 770 includes && chmod 660 includes/config.php
```

3. If you are still developing Magento, run the following for Development permissions:

   chown -R www-data:www-data . && find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && find app/ -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find skin/ -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find media/ -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find var/ -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && chmod 770 scheduler_cron.sh && chmod 770 cron.sh && chmod 770 sitemap/ && chmod 770 . && find lib/ -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;